# How to show a surface in projective space is irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ has dimension $n-1$. So for example quadric surfaces have dimension 2 inside $\mathbb{P}^3$.
In general I'm looking for a strategy to show that given a polynomial equation for a hypersurface is irreducible, i.e. they are algebraic sets that cannot be written as the union of two proper algebraic subsets. For example taking as an example (from Wikipedia):

$$xy = zw$$

or a cubic surface like:

$$wx^2 + xyz +y^3 = 0$$

How do I show that these surfaces are irreducible?

Comment: You want to show that these polynomials are irreducible.

Comment: What @Qi Zhu said. Maybe assume that these are reducible and obtain some strange contradiction.

Comment: @toolfan3 ok so for the cubic polynomial, what sort of factorisation do I need to look for. I assume it would it would be something like a quadratic times linear, but I am not sure how to explictly write that out.

Comment: Well I suppose I could give you a hint! Remember that if a polynomial has a root $a$, then $f(a)$=$0$, so $(x-a)$ is a factor of $f(a)$. (This is over a field). Also, we have that a polynomial $f(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$ with $integer$ coefficients is irreducible if the root of $f(x)$ $r/s$ does not obey $r|a_0$ and $s|a_n$. (But this is only if $f$ has a rational root). So maybe try and find a root of this polynomial and show that $(x-a)$ does not divide the cubic polynomial? (I don't really know I am just throwing ideas).

Comment: For instance, consider $y-x+1=0$. A root of this is $x=1$. But, $(x-1)$ does not divide $y=x+1$.

Comment: There is no straightforward way to show irreducibility of a general multivariate polynomial. For the cubic you may e.g. take mod z via the reduction criterion and then apply the Eisenstein criterion to conclude.

Comment: @toolfan3 Sorry, your comments do not make much sense for this question. The rational root theorem (which is just a consequence of minimal polynomials for integral extensions) does not help when the ground ring is a field and in your latest comment $x=1$ is not a root of the polynomial, the zeroes are exactly given by $y-x =1$ (your example is linear after all). The theory of irreducible polynomials for multiple variables is not quite as „easy“ as that for one variable.